# How much connection to mySQL server at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I didn't use mySQL before. Anybody can tell me how much is the max number of conection to mySQL server at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

The number of connections allowed is controlled by the max_connections system variable. Beginning with MySQL 5.1.15, its default value is 151 to improve performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/too-many-connections.html